# User Permission Denied in Git Push

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-fork

I am using Git to maintain the repository of my codebase and I am getting this error:

```
! [remote rejected] createdLocalBranch-> createdLocalBranch (permission denied)
```

while pushing my changes from this branch to my origin, which was forked branch, and I have cloned it into my local system.

Please let me know how we can fix it.

Steps to reproduce the issue :

1) fork the git url repo into our profile.

2) git clone into local system.

3) create new local branch (createdLocalBranch) and switch to it.

4) add or modify some changes and then commit by using git add and git commmit commands.

5) git push origin createdLocalBranch

Answer (score 0):

`origin` is repository nickname of original repository in your git `config` file so you can't push on origin because you haven't permission for that.

Add your own repo address with any specified name and then push with that name and branch name.

```
$ git remote add repo_nickname git://github.com/username/the_repo
```

Then push on your own repo

```
$ git push repo_nickname createdLocalBranch
```

Comment: i have checked the git config file remote.origin.url=https://github.com/username/repo_name 
where repo_name is pointing to my forked url so in this case also i don't have rights to push my commits.